# Mac App - Distributed Version of Help Not Working Fully. Links broken

Tags: macos, anchor, help-viewer

Mac App - Distributed Version of Help Not Working Fully.
Development machine  : OS X 10.8.2, on late 2008 MBP , Xcode 4.5.2

The app has a nine html page help system. Each page shares a sidebar menu with
nine choices. Each menu choice involves a link of the following type:

```
<a href="help:anchor=anchor_name bookID=com.mycompany.myapp.help">
```

This menu system link work as intended on my development machine.

When I distribute the app to another machine (OS X 10.6.8) using either of the following methods the help system loads the title page but the anchor links fail to work:

```
1. Transfer a debug version of app to another machine.
2. Use Archive to produce an install PKG file. In this 
method I deliver the PKG to a tester, using a Development Provisioning Profile
that includes the UUID of the target machine.
```

Can anyone please suggest a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem went away with OS X 10.8.3